# MySQL insert value with operation

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
- city1  city2 distance
- BAL   BOS   200
- BAL   HKG   8406
- DET   BAL   408
- BAL   LOS   2329
- ATL   BAL   576
```

And now I need to populate a new table taking the distance between any two cities to be the addition of distance via BAL

For example from DET to HKG = 408+8406 =8814
and the population need to be in pair so like ('DET','HKG',8814) along with ('HKG','DET',8814)

Not sure how to implement this query. Thanks!

Comment: How many stops can you have between 2 cities? Just the one (BAL)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works perfectly in MySQL, but I tried this in SQL Server and it works. The table is named Distance.

```
select distinct cities1.city as city1, cities2.city as city2
, (select top 1 distance from Distance where cities1.city = city1 or cities1.city = city2 ) 
+ (select top 1 distance from Distance where cities2.city = city2 or cities2.city = city1) as distance
 from
(select city1 as city from Distance
union select city2 as city from Distance) as cities1
join
(select city1 as city from Distance
union select city2 as city from Distance) as cities2
on cities1.city <> cities2.city
```

Then you can just insert the results of the query above into another table.
Basically what it does is joining the list of cities with itself, resulting in every possible pair of cities, then calculate the distance using the original table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Here Your '**DET**' is your starting city AND
'**HKG**' is your destination city

```
SELECT 
    ctc2.city1,
    ctc1.city2,
    ctc1.distance,
    ctc2.distance,
    (ctc1.distance+ctc2.distance) AS total_distance
FROM 
    city_to_city ctc1 
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT 
        city1,
        city2,
        distance 
    FROM 
        city_to_city 
    WHERE 
        city1='DET'
) ctc2 ON ( city2=ctc1.city1 AND ctc2.city2= ctc1.city1 ) 
WHERE 
    ctc1.city2='HKG' 
    AND ctc1.city1='BAL'
```